# Build a "with-query-replace-description" macro

Tags: query-replace

In the company where I work we use `Emacs` as the default editor for the `LaTeX` copy-editing tasks and we share some `Emacs` scripts to automate/guide some operations.

Actually I need to perform some query-replacements into the `LaTeX` code and to make my colleagues aware of the purpose of these replacements. To do this I use this kind of functions in my scripts:

```el
(query-replace-with-info "foo"
                         "bar"
                         "This replacement is appropriate in the following cases..."
                         nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

making `Emacs` behave like in the following figure:
[image]

To build my `query-replace-with-info` function I hacked the `perform-replace` function in this way: https://pastebin.com/79y7PKP7

The problem with this is that I cannot easily mantain the code if `perform-replace` will be updated in newer `Emacs` versions.

So I'd like to write a macro in this form:

```el
(with-query-replace-description
 "This replacement is appropriate in the following cases..."
 (query-replace "foo"
                "bar"
               nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

The description could be displayed in a temp-buffer.

Any suggestions?

**Info added**

I added an extra argument `INFO-STRING` to the original `perform-replace` function:

```el
(defun perform-replace-with-info (from-string replacements
                          query-flag regexp-flag INFO-STRING  delimited-flag
                          &optional repeat-count map start end backward region-noncontiguous-p)
...
```

and, in the `let` arguments, I added:

```el
(info-string (if INFO-STRING
              (propertize
               (concat INFO-STRING "\n\n")
               'face '(:foreground "goldenrod"
                           ;; :background "DarkGoldenrod1"
                           ))
            ;; *ELSE*
            ""))
```

Finally I modified the original `message` argument in the `let` args, this way:

```el
(message
          (if query-flag
          (concat ; <-- The magic
           info-string ; <--
           (apply 'propertize
              (substitute-command-keys
               "Query replacing %s with %s: (\\<query-replace-map>\\[help] for help) ")
              minibuffer-prompt-properties)))))
```

<del>Can this be done with the *advice* tecnique suggested by Drew in the comments?</del> (I just read that *advice* could be evil... please ignore this last question.)

Comment: It sounds like using Emacs *advice* would be appropriate. Even if changes are made to `perform-replace`, it sounds like you're just wrapping what it does with a function that displays some text. If I'm missing what you're saying, maybe say in your question why Emacs advice wouldn't be appropriate, to give a better idea of what you need/want.

Comment: I didn't know about *advice*! Thanks. But I'm not sure if I can use it in this case. I added an extra argument (the INFO_STRING) to the original `perform-replace` function and I concatenated (`(concat)`) it to the original message diplayed by the function. `message` is a variable declared in the `let` part of fhe `perform-replace` function.

Comment: Advice is not evil. It's just one more tool at your disposal. Of course, like anything it has its drawbacks/limitations. It sounded to me like you were asking about modifying an existing function, and advice is one way to do that, without source-code surgery. See Emacs Wiki [Advice](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Advice) and [Advice vs Hooks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdviceVsHooks).

Comment: @Drew, ok, thanks. I was just scared by the Richard Stallman's words about Advice.

Comment: RMS was only stating the policy for *code that's to be included as part of Emacs*. And that's a good policy. (And it's unfortunately no longer respected thoroughly, since the move to the new `nadvice` system.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been successfully using this solution for quite some time now:

```el
(defmacro with-interactive-tasks-explanation (MESSAGE &rest body)
  "It allows displaying, in a dedicated buffer resized to the
necessary minimum, instructions, tips, and clarifications on the
interactive operations present within the macro body."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let* ((message-buffer-name "*INTERACTIVE TASKS EXPLANATION*")
          (message-buffer (get-buffer-create message-buffer-name)))
     (unwind-protect
         (save-window-excursion
           (display-buffer-in-side-window
            message-buffer
            '((side . bottom)
              (slot . -1)
              (dedicated . t)))
           (with-current-buffer message-buffer
             (insert (make-string (window-width) ?/))
             (insert "\n\n")
             (insert ,MESSAGE)
             (insert "\n\n")
             (insert (make-string (window-width) ?/))
             (let ((TEMP-BUFFER-OVERLAY (make-overlay (point-min) (point-max))))
               (overlay-put TEMP-BUFFER-OVERLAY 'face 'shadow)
               (overlay-put TEMP-BUFFER-OVERLAY 'evaporate t))
             (fit-window-to-buffer (get-buffer-window (buffer-name)) nil 4 nil nil t)
             )
           ,@body
           )
       (kill-buffer message-buffer-name))))
```

The above macro can be used to wrap other kinds of interactive tasks.

1. `query-replace-explained` function:

```el
(defun query-replace-explained (from-string to-string info-string
                                            &optional delimited start end)
  (let ((start (if start
                   start
                 (point-min-marker)))
        (end (if end
                 end
               (point-max-marker))))

    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (when (search-forward-ifp from-string end t)
        (with-interactive-tasks-explanation info-string
          (query-replace from-string to-string delimited start end))))))
```

1. `query-replace-explained` function:

```el
(defun query-replace-regexp-explained (regexp to-string info-string
                                              &optional delimited start end)
  (let ((start (if start
                   start
                 (point-min-marker)))
        (end (if end
                 end
               (point-max-marker)))
        ;; This is crucial!

        ;; - "search-space-regexp" defines the regexp used by search-forward* to interpret
        ;; spaces

        ;; - "search-whitespace-regexp" defines the regexp used by query-replace-regexp to
        ;; interpret spaces and is activated by "replace-regexp-lax-whitespace"

        ;; - For this function to work properly, it is necessary for
        ;; "search-space-regexp" to match "search-whitespace-regexp" if
        ;; "replace-regexp-lax-whitespace" is "t"
        (search-spaces-regexp (if replace-regexp-lax-whitespace
                                  search-whitespace-regexp
                                search-spaces-regexp)))

    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (when (search-forward-regexp-ifp regexp end t)
        (with-interactive-tasks-explanation
         info-string
         (query-replace-regexp regexp to-string delimited start end))))))
```

**Usage.**

```el
(query-replace-explained
 "foo"
 "bar"
 "You need to replace \"foo\" with \"bar\" for example purpose"
 nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

[image]

or:

```el
(with-interactive-tasks-explanation
    "You need to replace \"foo\" with \"bar\" for example purpose"
  (query-replace
   "foo"
   "bar"
   nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use advice only in the last resort.  Preferred approaches, in order:

1. Hooks. Many Emacs operations allow you to add your own functions to be called in response to events triggered by those operations: `before-save-hook`, `after-save-hook`, etc etc.
2. Failing that, write your own command that "decorates" the original command, adding behavior before or after a call to the original (or both).
3. If the change you want cannot be achieved thus, for example, if the change you want needs to occur within the body of the original command, then copy, rename and modify the original's code (or use advice, see below).
4. If you really need system-wide, ongoing, transparent replacement of the original, you can instead copy and modify without renaming, but there are big problems, one of which you have noted, that your changes may break a future version. It has to be your responsibility to make sure that this doesn't happen.
5. Advice. It seems like a miracle cure for all ills, but it also has its own problems. Its transparency can be a problem as well as a benefit, since other users (or you after a few months) may not know/remember it is there. Keep it very, very simple, clean and uncluttered.